# Best practices when writing large equations?

Tags: math-mode, equations

This is pretty much a code formatting question. Suppose I had a huge equation with a lot of structure. Normally, I just let it run forever into the great right void, and let the text editor line wrapping take care of the readability. However, that is just not tractable with some of the larger equations that I have to deal with, so what I'm going to run off here are a few styling choices that I've and let you, the benevolent LaTeX gurus correct me if any of those are wrong, or if you have any that I should be using:

1. label on a separate line at the end of the equation. Some linters complain about this.
2. The entire equation is indented.
3. Line break at each equals sign.
4. Line break within each monomial, if it's large enough.
5. Each term starts with an indented plus or minus or rarely a `\times` which is indented further.
6. Each line ending is protected by a `%` to ensure that line breaks are purely for the reader. **EDIT** this is redundant. Math mode space isn't always inserted as space.
7. Summation and integration signs are another indentation block. Paired `\left` and `\right` too.

As an example:

```
 \begin{align}
    \begin{split}
      \mathbf{F}_p(t)
      =
      \sum_i g_i m_i \omega_i^2
       \Bigg\{
        \left[
         \mathbf{q}_i(0) - \frac{g_i}{\omega_i^2}\mathbf{x}(0)
        \right]
       \cos \omega_i t + \frac{\dot{\mathbf{q}}_i(0)}{\omega_i} \,
       \sin \omega_i t
       \Bigg\},
      \label{eq:noise-classical}
    \end{split}
  \end{align}
```

Compared with the standard:

```
\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
      \mathbf{q}_i(t) -\frac{ g_i}{\omega_i^2}\mathbf{x}(t) = &\left[
        \mathbf{q}_i(0) - \frac{ g_i}{\omega_i^2}\mathbf{x}(0) \right]
      \cos \omega_i t + \dot{\mathbf{q}}_i(0) \frac{\sin \omega_i
        t}{\omega_i} - g_i \int_0^t ds \, \dot{\mathbf{x}}(s)\frac{\cos
        \omega_i(t-s)}{\omega_i^2}. \label{eq:bath-motion-classical-int}
    \end{split}
\end{align}
```

Comment: As you haven't (yet) provided an example of a longish equation you tend to have to deal with in your line of work, I doubt it's possible to assess meaningfully whether the input formatting criteria you've listed are too burdensome (and hence actually might detract from code readability), about right, or insufficiently burdensome (and therefore also detract from code readability). In short, do consider editing your posting to provide a somewhat representative longish equation -- and how you've chosen to input it.

Comment: but I still can't really work out what you are asking. If you are asking about the input, then why make up rules? it doesn't really matter:  just break wherever convenient. If asking about the output then you need to give more information.